# Several errors ';' expected in package.json after installing ESLint airbnb

Tags: reactjs, eslint, package.json

**After installing eslint packages from airbnb** I have received errors in package.json,which say that I'm missing semicolons, while before installation of packages error did not occur. The problem is shown in the image below.

[image]

Code from `.eslintrc`:

`{
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 6
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "browser": true
    }
}`

The questions are:

1. why these errors are occuring?
2. how to fix this?

Comment: are you on windows and file format is `LF` ?

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 18.04 lts. Yes, file format is LF

Comment: cause sometimes the error comes from CRLF or LF,  but typescript even should understand format of JSON file. unless there is a very old version of the typescript is installed globally, it is recommended to disable TSlint plugin and Enable/Install ESLint plugin

Comment: `"ecmaVersion": 2016` or `es6`

Comment: iIt's probabl about your eslint filter. It shoudn't just include everything with extension `.js*` but you need a list of extensions, e.g. `.js, .jsx` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uninstall/disable `tslint` on your visual studio code for the project, that error comes from `tslint`.

Comment: your solution is correct. Nevertheless, in the other project the same problem occured and the restart of Visual Studio Code helped to solve the problem. I don't know exactly the reason, why restart removes this errors, but it does.

Comment: I can't be sure about that, but it seems by default tslint should be disable automatically for `.js` file, so perhaps restarting the app would fix it.

Comment: @mkfakhrusy I was told in the company that sometimes **eslint cache** crashes and the restart of source code editor helps